# Relational Database in Rails: how many references do I need?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-schema, foreign-key-relationship

In my rails app, a Person has_many :measurements and a Measurement belongs_to a :person.
I added the associations to the model files. Then I wrote TWO migrations for this associations.

```
class AddMeasurementRefToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :people, :measurement, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

and

```
class AddPersonRefToMeasurements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :measurements, :person, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

My `schema.rb` looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150730121109) do

  create_table "measurements", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.integer  "weight"
    t.integer  "bmi_calc"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "person_id"
  end

  add_index "measurements", ["person_id"], name: "index_measurements_on_person_id"

  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.float    "length"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.integer  "measurement_id"
  end
add_index "people", ["measurement_id"], name: "index_people_on_measurement_id"

end
```

Now I am in doubt if I really do need *both* migrations. Now, I have a foreign_key in both models. Wouldn't one be enough? 
(And if so, which one of the 2 migrations should I roll back?)

Comment: One is enough. You don't need to add `measurement_id` in `people`.

Comment: @Pavan Could you change your comment in an answer, please?

Comment: I reverted my migration ```maud$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20150730091740
== 20150730091740 AddMeasurementRefToPeople: reverting ========================
-- remove_reference(:people, :measurement, {:index=>true, :foreign_key=>true}) ```  There is no mention of this un-migration in my migrations list, so the reverting doesn't show up. My DB schema.rb however has been updated and reflects the reverted migration. Am I  supposed to see a new migration file in the migrations folder?

Comment: @Mauddev Running a migration down is intended to reverse the schema changes. It does not remove or revert any file changes.

The AddMeasurementRefToPeople migration should be permanently removed and never run again. So after migrating down (as you already did in your last comment -- this reverted the changes to your schema), you should delete the migration file. It should be named `db/migrate/20150730091740_add_measurement_ref_to_people.rb`. If this file was not removed it would be run again the next time you did `rake db:migrate` (which runs all pending migrations in the up direction).

Comment: @WizardofOgz Thank you! That makes sense. 
In the meantime, I found another solution: I added a RemoveMeasurementRefFromPeople migration. But your solution is much more neat, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

According to you association,one person has many measurements and measurement belongs to only person.

You only need person foreign key in measurements table. No need to add the `measurement_id` to person as there are many measurements for one person..

so `AddPersonRefToMeasurements` is enough

in models you should do

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :measurements
end


class Measurement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```